# Purpose of clientcert = 1 mean in postgresql configuration

Tags: postgresql

What is the purpose of appending clientcert = 1 in the pg_hba.conf file in postgresql?

For example:

```
      hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 cert clientcert=1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add `clientcert=1` to hostssl options for checking the client certificates, otherwise everyone will be granted access in your setup.

> When `clientcert` is not specified or is set to `0`, the server will still
>   verify presented client certificates against its CA list, if one is
>   configured, — but **it will not insist that a client certificate be
>   presented.**
>
> Source: [Using Client Certificates from Postgres Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CLIENT-CERTIFICATES)

Comment: the options in 2023 are `clientcert=verify-ca` or `clientcert=verify-full`